# Сравнение двух массивов и запись результата в базу Mysql

Tags: php, массивы, сравнение

Есть к примеру первый массив:

---

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 123
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 456
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 789
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1010
    )
)
```

И второй:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 123
        [name] => some name1
        [is_match] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 999999
        [name] => some name2
        [is_match] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 789
        [name] => some name3
        [is_match] => 1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 101022243
        [name] => some name4
        [is_match] => 1
    )
)
```

---

Как сравнить объекты массивов, и если объект не соответствует, изменить is_match на 0.

Comment: Было бы интересно увидеть ваши попытки

Comment: @Bookin, Да я просто пробовал сравнивать == в цикле, так-как не сильно дружу с функциями  массивов, но потом понял что идея глупая, и нужно попросить помощи)

Comment: Лучше попытки отображать в вопросах, что бы люди могли подсказать что не так и с чем конкретно помочь

Comment: И тут один фиг сравнивать одно с другим, хоть == хоть как то иначе

Comment: @Bookin, Да но Ваш вариант посимпатичней будет)))

Comment: @Bookin, Всё же не работает...

Comment: Ну можно было бы привести тест ошибки или чего там происходит, поправил, пример - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/45928f9cef96efa6b1a0403766a99118351ffc17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$array1 = [
    ['id'=>123],
    ['id'=>456],
    ['id'=>789],
    ['id'=>1010]
];
$array2 = [
    ['id'=>123, 'is_match'=>1],
    ['id'=>999999, 'is_match'=>1],
    ['id'=>789, 'is_match'=>1],
    ['id'=>101022243, 'is_match'=>1]
];


$ids = array_column($array1, 'id');
array_walk($array2, function(&$item) use($ids){
    if(!in_array($item['id'], $ids)) $item['is_match']=0;
});

var_dump($array2);
```

[Пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/45928f9cef96efa6b1a0403766a99118351ffc17)